# How to get a list of getters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

```js
class Category {
  constructor(
    readonly _title: string,
  ) { }

  get title() {
    return this._title
  }
}

 type Categories = typeof categories

 const categories = {
  get pets() {
    return new class extends Category {
      constructor() {
        super(
          'Pets',
        )
      }

      get dishes() {
        return new Category(
          'Pets dishes',
        )
      }
    }
  },
  get cloth() {
    return new class extends Category {
      constructor() {
        super(
          'Cloth',
        )
      }

      get accessories() {
        return new Category(
          'Accessories',
        )
      }
    }
  },
}

Object.entries(categories).forEach(([, category]) => {
  // Actual logs:
  // ["_title"]
  // ["_title"]
  // Expected logs: 
  // ["dishes"]
  // ["accessories"]
  console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(category))
})
```

Why does `Reflect.ownKeys` return something different from what I expect?
How to get a list of getters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dishes` and `accessories` are not **own** properties. They are properties defined on the prototype of the anonymous classes. On the other hand, `_title` **is** a own property of the created objects, as that property was added by the constructor (via the super call, in the constructor of `Category`).

If you want to only get `dishes` and `accessories` as a result, then iterate the prototypes:

```
  console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(Object.getPrototypeOf(category))
                     .filter(prop => prop !== 'constructor'));
```

Answer (score -3):

The Reflect.ownKeys(category) will return the own property keys of the instance, which in this case, is just the _title property. It doesn't include the getter methods.

If you want to get a list of getters, you need to iterate over the prototype chain using **Object.getOwnPropertyNames and Object.getPrototypeOf**. Here's how you can modify
your code to achieve that:

```
Object.entries(categories).forEach(([, category]) => {
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(category));
});
```

In this modification, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(category) is used to get the own property names of each category, including the getter methods. This will output the expected logs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy